# Which apartment is the class object in?

Tags: winapi, com

Suppose we have an in-process server. The client thread is in the MTA, but the object is not free-threaded (i.e. lives in an STA).

Does `CoGetClassObject` create the class object in the MTA, or in a new STA?

Does a class object always create objects in the same apartment that the class object resides, or can it create them in other apartments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your COM server is in-process COM class marked as "apartment" threaded and you are instantiating it from MTA thread.

Your `CoGetClassObject` (or `CoCreateInstance`) call does the following:

- using the `CLSID` passed, COM detects the server needs STA and the caller is MTA
- STA is created if needed, that is if the process does not have STA to use use, COM creates a worker thread
- COM loads the server DLL if necessary and calls `DllGetClassObject` on the STA thread
- COM creates proxy/stub pair for the obtained class factory and passes control back to the caller thread
- the MTA callers receive `IClassFactory*` interface pointer, which points to proxy and not to real factory; the proxy takes calls on its MTA end to transfer them into native STA of the server
- further client calls are received on MTA threads and are internally passed to the STA thread, where the real class factory calls takes place and then real instantiation occurs (marhsaling)

COM will do its best to transfer all [legal] calls to the mentioned STA. If you find ways to fool it, e.g. you obtain direct pointer to class factory in your MTA code (via `GetModuleHandle`, `GetProcAddress`, `DllGetClassObject` OR getting the pointer on STA then passing it to MTA without marshaling), it WILL work on the start even though might have some unexpected behavior. Once in while later when/if you reach a call through proxy, you will get [`RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172314) error. That is, you are in general interested to comply with COM rules even though sometimes their violation do not result in failures immediately.

Comment: So the class object is in a new STA , and then when you call `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` that instance appears in the same STA as the class object was?

Comment: Yes, server instance lives in STA according to its registration. MTA caller deals with proxy interfaces. COM does the magic to transfer calls back and forth.

Comment: If the same class object is used to create multiple objects , does each object get its own STA, or do they all live in the same STA?

Comment: Good question. As long as you keep that reference to `IClassFactory` pointer, you have the guarantee that the object will be created on the same STA thread where on background the real class factory lives. If you release and then begin from fresh - I am not sure if COM guarantees use of the same STA but practical chances are high that it will still be the same STA. That is, the existing STA is likely to be reused, but it is not something that has to happen. It might so happen that that STA simply self-terminate on idleness by the time of supposed reuse.